# I have a program (.exe) made in Visual Studio 2019, and want to run it on a computer that doesnt have Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I keep getting the error that uctrbased.dll cannot be fournd and VDRUNTIME140.dll cannot be found. Has anyone else experienced this/found a solution that does not involve downloading something, but rather changing where or how I compile my code or something in the code?

Comment: Perhaps you should start your research by not mistyping the file names. ;) // Does your program do anything fancy?

Answer (score 2):

> I keep getting the error that uctrbased.dll cannot be found and VDRUNTIME140.dll cannot be found.

**ucrtbase.dll** is installed by downloading and installing the appropriate version of the Windows SDK.  You need to install the same version you have installed on the machine that compiled the code.  The Windows 10 SDK component you need to install is the `Universal C Runtime`.

**There is no other way to get this file other than to install the `Universal C Runtime` 
which is installed by installing the correct version of the [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)**

> I keep getting the error that VDRUNTIME140.dll cannot be found.

`VDRUNTIME140.dll` is not the correct filename, but based on what is correct about the name of that particular file, you need to install [`Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3`](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/).  **The correct file name would have to be `VCRuntime140.dll`.**

Comment: In order to view the older downloads, on the [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) website, you have to signup for a free visual studio subscription.